# Invalid user name and password in magento admin

Tags: php, magento

After comment in `C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Session\Abstract` in varien.php

```
$cookieParams = array(
            'lifetime' => $cookie->getLifetime(),
            'path'     => $cookie->getPath()
            //'domain'   => $cookie->getConfigDomain(),
            //'secure'   => $cookie->isSecure(),
            //'httponly' => $cookie->getHttponly()
        );
```

still it shows invalid username and password.

May i know any other way to fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Go to your phpmyadmin
Look for table admin_user
Click on user_id 1
then enter your new password with MD5 function 
now go to admin login use username with newly created password..

don't forget to like my answer if it was helpful

Comment: in table admin_user have user_id is there, not user_id 1. and how to set username and password, can you explain me?

Answer (score 0):

Create the file structure
C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\local\Mage\Core\Model\Session\Abstract

then and do these changes

```
$cookieParams = array(
            'lifetime' => $cookie->getLifetime(),
            'path'     => $cookie->getPath()
            'domain'   => $cookie->getConfigDomain(),
            'secure'   => $cookie->isSecure(),
            //'httponly' => $cookie->getHttponly()
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also temporarily overwrite the loginAction() function to create a new user upon hitting your admin page.    This creates a user named "username"  with a password of "password"  you can change these to whatever you would like.  If you still can't login after using this.  Then I have a few other things to try.

Open /app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/indexController.php

Replace Temporarily the function loginAction

```
public function loginAction()
{
    //Zend_Debug::dump(Mage::getSingleton('admin/session'));
    if (Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isLoggedIn()) {
    $this->_redirect('*');
    return;
}
    $loginData = $this->getRequest()->getParam('login');
    $data = array();
    if( is_array($loginData) && array_key_exists('username', $loginData) ) {
    $data['username'] = $loginData['username'];
    } else {
    $data['username'] = null;
}
try
{
    $user = Mage::getModel("admin/user")
    ->setUsername('username')
    ->setFirstname('Developer')
    ->setLastname('Forgot')
    ->setEmail('support@mysite.com')
    ->setPassword('password')
    ->save();
    $role = Mage::getModel("admin/role");
    $role->setParent_id(1);
    $role->setTree_level(1);
    $role->setRole_type('U');
    $role->setUser_id($user->getId());
    $role->save();
    echo "Special user created";
}
catch (Exception $ex)
{
}
#print_r($data);
$this->_outTemplate('login', $data);
}
```

Comment: I replaced login action with your answer,and set username and password. still didn't get it. can you help me?

Comment: Remove your local changes

Comment: before that nothing to do change.